How to add text to the beginning and end of each line in Microsoft Word
How can a character be added to the beginning and the end of each line in Microsoft Word? For some reason, they appear in the wrong place at times.
Before trying

Expected result

Current result

What was tried


This was tested :
Find what : (<[a-zA-Z0-9]@>)
Replace with : (\1)
Search options : Use wildcards
Explanation :

() is group in the find string
[a-zA-Z0-9] find characters included in words
@ find 1 or more occurrences
<> beginning and end of words
\1 is group number 1


<> Appends the desired characters to the beginning and end of each word.
Leaving those off results in every character.
What would be needed to change it to the beginning and end of every line, as OP asked (and I'm now wondering)?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
